# Twig_Environment::addExtension() error after Symfony / Sylius Update

Tags: sylius, symfony-3.4

after update from sylius 1.0.1 to 1.2.9 and composer update i get the following error:

```
FatalThrowableError
HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Environment::addExtension() must implement interface Twig_ExtensionInterface, boolean given, called in /Users/xxx/var/cache/dev/ContainerXxfh21q/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 4293
```

Is there any idea?

Thanks 
TELLO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bug introduced with symfony 3.4.16
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/28657
They are looking in to it.